# Sending money to friends and family with PayPal

Tags: paypal

I am looking for a PHP code sample for how to send money with PayPal via the friends and family method. Anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 0):

There is no code or API interface for Send Money. For general use, you can redirect a user to https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/homepage

If you have a specific recipient in mind, that recipient can create a https://www.paypal.me link